# How do I write a one-liner cd command for the following case?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 2 directories
**testing_dir

testing_dir_win**

So I need to cd to **testing_dir**. But here is the case

the directories can be
**testing_dir or testing_dir-2.1.0 

testing_dir_win or testing_dir_win-1.3.0**

and my script should only take **testing_dir or testing_dir-2.1.0** (based on which is available)

I have the long way of writing it:

```
str=`ls folder_name|grep ^testing_dir`
arr=(${str//" "/ })
ret=""
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    if [[ $i != *"testing_dir_win"* ]] ; then
            ret=$i
    fi
done
```

but is there a one-liner for this problem? something like `cd testing_dir[\-]?`(This doesn't work by the way).

Comment: Are you asking how to write a script/function, or how to type something by hand? If the latter I'd argue this is off topic here and belongs on [UNIX.se]; if the former, why do you care if it's a one liner or not? -- correctness, robustness, maintainability, etc should be more important than terseness for code that's going to be reused every time you call it.

Comment: Also, why are you passing `folder_name` to `ls` when the `cd` requires the `ls` to be against the current directory to make sense?

Comment: ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) That includes `ls dir | grep something` put into any array and then iterated over.  Better `for i in "folder_name/testing_dir"*` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script contains

```
shopt -s extglob
```

you can use:

```
cd testing_dir?(-[[:digit:]]*) || exit
```

...if you have a guarantee that only one match will exist.

Without that guarantee, you can directly set

```
arr=( testing_dir?(-[[:digit:]]*) )
cd "${arr[0]}" || exit
```

Answer (score 1):

use command with grep filters:

```
cd `ls | grep -w testing_dir`
```

this command will match the testing_dir directory without worrying for version.

P.S in case of many versions it will go inside the earliest version so add "head -1, tail -1" according to your usecase

Comment: As currently written this fails if the directory name contains spaces (or potentially other glob characters). Also see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: (also relevant is entry #1 in [BashPitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls))

Comment: This is working. @CharlesDuffy And as per my requirement there aren't any spaces in the directory name. Anyways thanks for the heads up.